# Flexible and fixed size. Make children pass size to parent?

Tags: flutter, listview

I am trying to make an interface that tries to do something very simple:

Prints a series of things in line and the last one is an scrollable (listview) that expands across all screen. It's making my life hell, however.

My problem is that the things it needs to print in line occupy don't adapt, I want them to "calculate and pass their size to the parent" so that the listview can be make to expand as much as possible WITHOUT eating the first elements on the screen or leaving them with unnecessary space.

Furthermore, the size of the firsts elements can change, they have a button that "dissects" into two.

This is more like my setup of widgets (and in parenthesis the class they are in):

```
Column(W1): 
|Flexible(W1):
||Column(W2)  <= Actually, I created a listview now because some problems.
|||conditional column(WX*) (1 children or 2)
|Flexible(W1)
||Divider(W3)
||Flexible
|||Layoutparamsbuilder(W3)
||||listviewbuilder(W4)
```

*This was in another widget, but there is no reason for it. There are 3 elems to show in screen, the first option shows 1, and the other option disables that one and shows the other 2, they are part of a state(changes while looking at it). I created a new column for simplicity (adding them programatically to the W2 column could be kind of a mess, but if doing so solves the issue i will do it)

I think the mistake is in between W1 and W2. But removing the "flexible" out of W1 makes a mess. It doesn't print anything. I need W2 to show all his shit and then back off, but instead it occupies half the screen.

Now, being in a single line is not a necessity, and I tried a Grid, thinking that I would solve all my problems. Is seemed perfect, but not at all! That's the only reason why W2 is a column.

Sorry for the long post. I made a shitty painting in pain showing ""my interface"":

Also, I have another tiny, unimportant question: The listview is meant for showing some sort of a "table" with several fields. An example: It shows (name, age, email). If the window expands horizontally, each field grows. Is there any widget that calculates this and, instead, adds a different field (name, age, email, phone) ? Tables not only don't do this, but they also don't scroll on their own, and my second option was to make a listview of listviews, making my real problem(the question) even worse xdddd.

Thank you very much, you are amazing people :).

[image]

I add the basic structure of the code code:

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Flexible( child : Widget1()),
          Expanded (child: Widget2())
          )],),


Widget1:
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration( border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(   ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Consumer>> (ListView(children: textfiel, row, row)
              ])
   Widger2: 
Column(
          children : [
            Divider(), Row(), Divider(), Text(), Sizedbox(), Flexible(LayoutBuilder(Sizedbox(height: contrains.height, child: Listview(rows....)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you need to use Expanded Widget and pass the ListView or whatever your Scrollable widget as a child.
Check out the links below:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo

If you still have this problem, you can share your code to make the problem more clear.

Comment: just edited it with the general code. I want to constrain the parent, not to expand the child